# Como cortar cadena y unirla en una variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

**esta1seg0831a.txt** mi archivo que deseo cortar

```
file_name = esta1seg0831a.txt

year = 2016
month = file_name[8:10]
day = file_name[10:12]
estacion = file_name[:4]
nombre = file_name

folder = [year,month,day,estacion]
```

Mi resultado de salida es = *[2016, '08', '31', 'esta']*

como puedo obtener: *year,month,day* de la siguiente manera:

```
2016-08-31
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se llaman en inglés *slices*, que significan algo así como rebanadas. Cuando cuentas las *rebanadas* en Python desde el inicio al fin, empiezan en 0 (cero) **antes** del primer carácter y se cuentan entre caracteres **hasta** que abarcas **toda** la rebanada.

Mira la siguiente imagen:

[image: Slicing]

En el caso del nombre que propones,

```
 e s t a 1 s e g 0 8 3 1 a . t x t
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                 0 8                 <-- mes [8:10]
                     3 1             <-- día [10:12]
```

La rebanada `08` que llamaremos *mes* se encuentra entre el 8 (que es donde empieza la rebanada y el 10 que es donde termina).

La rebanada `31` que llamamos *día* se encuentra entre el 10 (el índice *antes* del carácter) y el 12 (el índice después del último carácter de la rebanada).

Lo que quieres, queda entonces, de la siguiente manera:

```
fn = 'esta1seg0831a.txt'
estacion = '2016-%s-%s' % (fn[8:10], fn[10:12])
print (estacion)
2016-08-31
```

Como puedes observar estoy usando sustitución de caracteres en la variable `estación`. Uso `%s` para indicar que se debe sustituir ese marcador por el primer valor que se encuentre. El segundo marcador se sustituye por el segundo valor y así sucesivamente. Debe haber igual número de marcadores y de valores que los sustituyan.

Puedes ver como se ejecuta el código aquí: http://codepad.org/99ejFXzj

### Edición

El compañero @jose-hermosilla-rodrigo nos ofrece una alternativa mas elegante:

```
fn = 'esta1seg0831a.txt'
estacion = "-".join(["2016", fn[8:10], fn[10:12] ])
print(estacion)
```

Puedes ver su eficacia en este enlace: http://codepad.org/BfT9cvrU

Comment: Qué tal `"-".join(["2016", fn[8:10], fn[10:12] ])`?

Comment: Muy buena! Me parece mas elegante.

Comment: Gracias por añadirlo en tu respuesta!! =)

Comment: excelente explicacion @toledano pude resolver mi problema satisfactoriamente.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo muy eficiente la alternativa propuesta